# How to select multiple rows based on header values?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, selection

I wish to iterate over rows of a Pandas dataframe while only checking for similarity within a few columns among the rows. Then, I want to check for a similarity condition, followed by a date comparison (which one is earlier/later) and apply corresponding changes to one element of the row selected.

For selecting particular rows, I kind of want something like this:

```
p=z["product_name", "Category 1", "Category 2", "Features"].iloc[i-1:i]
```

I know it's not correct, but it's just to give an idea. Select a row with only a few particular headers out of many.

```py
i=1
while (i<=len(z)):
    j=i+1
    p=z["product_name", "Category 1", "Category 2", "Features"].iloc[i-1:i]
    p=p.to_string(index=False)
    while(j<=len(z)):
        q=z["product_name", "Category 1", "Category 2", "Features"].iloc[j-1:j]
        q=q.to_string(index=False)
        if (p==q):
            if(z["Update Date"].iloc[i-1:i]>z["Update Date"].iloc[j-1:j]):
                 z.drop(j, axis=0)
        j=j+1
    i=i+1
```

I know that most of this code is actually wrong but this is the approach I'm trying. Please suggest a better approach/function that solves this problem.

Comment: I know, I've mentioned it already in the questions that it's wrong. I just wanted the give the viewer an idea of what I'm looking for. I want to iterate over rows of a dataframe, selecting only a few columns at once.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your question exactly, But there are Basic Issue in your code when you start i-1:i, it gives only one value why you use this line instead of directly one variable

```
p=z["product_name", "Category 1", "Category 2", "Features"].iloc[i-1:i]
```

try This:

```
p=z[["product_name", "Category 1", "Category 2", "Features"]].iloc[i-1:i]
```

Comment: I want exactly one row at once because I'm iterating over multiple rows-> checking condition -> and making required changes in the fields. The double square bracket worked well for me. Thanks a lot!!